# Convert code to function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, programming-languages, audiotoolbox

Hello everyone i need to convert this code to a function with 2 parameters in this case the first parameter is **News** and the second one **aif** can u do this ??

```
-(IBAction)news
{
CFURLRef        soundFileURLRef;
SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;
CFBundleRef mainBundle;
mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

// Get the URL to the sound file to play
soundFileURLRef  =  CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle,
                                             CFSTR ("News"),
                                             CFSTR ("aif"),
                                             NULL);

// Create a system sound object representing the sound file
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);

return;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the CFSTR thing is the problem, then the solution is:

```
-(void) playNews: (NSString*) news type: (NSString*) type
{
    CFURLRef        soundFileURLRef;
    SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;
    CFBundleRef mainBundle;
    mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

    // Get the URL to the sound file to play
    soundFileURLRef  =  CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle,
            (CFStringRef)news,
            (CFStringRef)type,
            NULL);

    // Create a system sound object representing the sound file
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
}
```

But the *(IBAction)* declaration makes no sense here because this method cannot be directly used from Interface Builder.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer and this is what i want but When I write PlayNews:@"news1" ofType:@"wav"; the xcode give me an error: expected ';' before 'type' can you help me sovle that

Comment: You need to put it in angular brackets:  [obj playNews: @"news" ofType: @"wav"];

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be an action received by a class from a user using a control, then the only thing you can do is `-(IBAction)nameOfAction:(id)sender;`. Otherwise, then you need to write the command to take the two arguments you require and call that from an `IBAction`.